# How to parse part of a YAML file in SnakeYaml

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am new to YAML and have parse a YAML config file that looks like:

```
applications:
  authentication:
    service-version: 2.0
    service-url: https://myapp.corp/auth
    app-env: DEV
    timeout-in-ms: 5000
    enable-log: true

  service1:
    enable-log: true
    auth-required: true
    app-env: DEV
    timeout-in-ms: 5000
    service-url: https://myapp.corp/service1
    service-name: SomeService1
    service-version: 1.1
    service-namespace: http://myapp.corp/ns/service1

  service2:
    enable-log: true
    auth-required: true
    app-env: DEV
    timeout-in-ms: 5000
    service-url: https://myapp.corp/service2
    service-name: SomeService2
    service-version: 2.0
    service-namespace: http://myapp.corp/ns/service2
```

I have to parse to following `Map` structure

```
+==================================+
| Key              |               |
+==================================+
| authentication   | AuthConfig    |
+----------------------------------+
| service1         | ServiceConfig |
+----------------------------------+
| service2         | ServiceConfig |
+----------------------------------+
```

`AuthConfig` and `ServiceConfig` are the custom objects in our system.

Can someone provide some hints how to do it?

Comment: Maybe is not a valid answer but you can use YamlBeans instead: http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/ that seems better documented

Comment: This project has been moved to GitHub and there they have very little documentation. In fact the documentations are worse than SnakeYaml. I may be missing something here, but do you have the links to YamlBeans documentation?

Comment: Yes, it has been moved: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans In Github README there is an explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 8):

There is a package for Java called [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) that handles mapping between [YAML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) (and JSON, and CSV, and XML) and Java objects. Most examples you will come across are for JSON, but the YAML link shows that switching is straight-forward. Everything goes through an `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
```

That can then be used to deserialize your object via reflection:

```
ApplicationCatalog catalog = mapper.readValue(yamlSource, ApplicationCatalog.class);
```

You would set up your classes something like this (I've made everything public for ease of example):

```
class ApplicationCatalog {
  public AuthConfig authentication;
  public ServiceConfig service1;
  public ServiceConfig service2;
}

class AuthConfig {
  @JsonProperty("service-version")
  public String serviceVersion;
  @JsonProperty("service-url")
  public String serviceUrl;
  @JsonProperty("app-env")
  public String appEnv;
  @JsonProperty("timeout-in-ms")
  public int timeoutInMs;
  @JsonProperty("enable-log")
  public boolean enableLog;
}

class ServiceConfig {
  ...
}
```

Notice the JsonProperty [annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) which is renaming your Java field to YAML field. I find this the most convenient way of dealing with JSON and YAML in Java. I've also had to use the [streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example) for really large objects.

Comment: BTW, Jackson actually uses SnakeYAML under the hood for YAML.

Comment: Thanks for replying; I am aware of Jackson APIs. We are using this for our REST services. I am also aware of the jackson-yml package. But I didn't want to use another wrapper over snakeyml lib. I will post once I find a convincing solution. Anyways, appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems like this is indeed the most convenient solution, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

So as you have the same properties in the Auth and Service configuration I simplified that in one class to show you here.

The YamlConfig class look like this:

```
public class YamlConfig {

  private Map<String, ServiceConfig> applications;

  //... getter and setters here
}
```

And the the Parser logic is something like that :

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(YamlConfig.class));
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/apps.yml"));
YamlConfig data = yaml.loadAs( input, YamlConfig.class);
```

I shared the full code in this gist:  https://gist.github.com/marceldiass/f1d0e25671d7f47b24271f15c1066ea3

Comment: This is a sample for a modified code, not the OP's original request. OP's YAML file uses dash( - ) as the separation while yours is using camelCase.