# How to serialize fields with custom names using snake yaml in Java

Tags: java, serialization, yaml, pojo, snakeyaml

I'm trying to serialize a Java instance having fields like follows.

```
public class Person{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {

        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {

        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {

        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

How do I serialize them in different names than the actual field names? In `Gson` this is possible by using `@SerializedName("first-name")` annotation as follows.

```
@SerializedName("first-name")
private String firstName;
```

Is there something similar to above in `snakeyaml`. The dependency details for `snakeyaml` is as follows,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

Below is the main class of the program with the answer provided by `flyx`

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Kasun");
        person.setLastName("Siyambalapitiya");

        Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Person.class);
        Representer representer = new Representer();
        TypeDescription personDesc = new TypeDescription(Person.class);
        personDesc.substituteProperty("first-name", Person.class, "getFirstName", "setFirstName");
        personDesc.substituteProperty("last-name", Person.class, "getLastName", "setLastName");
        constructor.addTypeDescription(personDesc);
        representer.addTypeDescription(personDesc);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor, representer);
        String yamlString = yaml.dumpAs(person, Tag.MAP, DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);

        Path updateDescriptorFilePath =
                Paths.get(File.separator + "tmp" + File.separator + "sample.json");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(updateDescriptorFilePath.toFile(), yamlString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

The above results in the following output

```
/tmp  cat sample.json
first-name: Kasun
last-name: Siyambalapitiya
firstName: Kasun
lastName: Siyambalapitiya
 /tmp 
```

Comment: Jackson can serialize to YAML (in fact, it uses SnakeYAML behind the scenes) and you can use the `@JsonProperty` annotation to do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217410/how-to-parse-part-of-a-yaml-file-in-snakeyaml/37356162

Answer (score 4):

```
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Person.class);
Representer representer = new Representer();
TypeDescription personDesc = new TypeDescription(Person.class);
personDesc.substituteProperty("first-name", String.class,
        "getFirstName", "setFirstName");
constructor.addTypeDescription(personDesc);
representer.addTypeDescription(personDesc);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor, representer);
// and then load /dump your file with it
```

Comment: You need to describe *what* is not working and show your code (edit the question).

Comment: I have added the code I have tried out, please have a look

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you need to define a `Representer` for dumping. Try again.

Comment: now the output has both values as follows, ` cat sample.json
first-name: Kasun
last-name: Siyambalapitiya
firstName: Kasun
lastName: Siyambalapitiya
`

Comment: I have updated the code and the output, please have a look

Comment: Hmm. This actually seems to be a limitation of SnakeYAML, see [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/issues/403/typedescriptionsubstituteproperty-doesnt). I cannot think of a trivial solution; you probably would need to subclass `TypeDescription` for a workaround :(

Comment: @Flyx   how do you do this for classes nested within the root class?

Comment: @DaBlick You can add type descriptions for any class, not just the root class. The code is the same, just keep the root class as constructor argument and add type descriptions for the relevant nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

For those running into this problem I solved it by using both a substitution and exclusion:

```
TypeDescription personDesc = new TypeDescription(Person.class);
personDesc.substituteProperty("first-name", Person.class, "getFirstName", "setFirstName");
personDesc.substituteProperty("last-name", Person.class, "getLastName", "setLastName");
personDesc.setExcludes("firstName", "lastName");
```

This worked for me - at least for dumping the YAML.

Comment: It should be
`personDesc.substituteProperty("first-name", String.class, "getFirstName", "setFirstName");`
As String is the property type
see: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/org/yaml/snakeyaml/TypeDescription.html#substituteProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-